# Insert items into Custom LinkedList in Order

Tags: java, sorting, insert, linked-list

I'm trying to insert items into a custom linked list, while keeping the list in order.

My work up to now is this:

```
public class CustomList {   

    public CustomList() {
        this.first = null;
    }
    public void insert(Comparable newThing) {
        Node point = this.first;
        Node follow = null;
        while (point != null && point.data.compareTo(newThing) < 0) {
            follow = point;
            point = point.next;
        }
        if (point == null) {
            Node newNode = new Node(newThing);
            newNode.next = this.first;
            this.first = newNode;
        } else {
            Node newNode = new Node(newThing);
            newNode.next = point;
            if (follow == null) {
                this.first = newNode;
            } else {
                follow.next = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
    private Node first;

    private class Node {

        public Comparable data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(Comparable item) {
            this.data = item;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get from this looks like it orders parts of the list, then starts over.

Example (I'm sorting strings):

Instead of getting something like `a,b,c,...,z`

I get `a,b,c,...,z,a,b,c,...,z,a,b,c,...,z`

So it looks like it doesn't "see" the whole list at certain points.

This is part of a HW assignment, so I'd appreciate suggestions, but let me try to figure it out myself!

Comment: Although it looks a lot like homework, I'm going to give you a small hint: are you sure that putting a node at the beginning of list always when `point == null` is OK?

Comment: Yes, its part of HW (I honestly forgot to write that, but it's fixed now).

As per your suggestion, am I right in thinking that since point==null can also happen at the end of the list, I should include that?

Comment: You could simplify it by beginning with `Node point = this;` instead of `Node point = this.first;`. Then you end up with `point == null` only at the end of the list. And yes, you are right in your assumptions.

Comment: @mouser, I'm not sure I follow. Since "this" is my Custom LL, that would just reference itself, and give an error. I want to point to the first Node (which is empty except for a .next).

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're definitely right :) Just treat that special case, when `first = null` as putting at the beginning of the list and in all other cases, when `point == null`, you should be at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you insert an element which is greater than all your existing elements?

You want to insert the element at the end, but in fact you are inserting it at start. And any later elements will then inserted before this (if they are smaller), or again at start.

Comment: What if instead of

if (point == null) {

I used:
 (point == null&&follow==null) {
            Node newNode = new Node(newThing);
            newNode.next = this.first;
            this.first = newNode;
  } else if (point==null) {
   Node newNode = new Node(newThing);
   newNode.next==null;
   point.next==newNode;

Comment: Looks better ... try it out. (I can't really read your code in a comment. If it still does not work, update the code in the question (there is an edit link), and describe what you are getting now.)